# Overcoming NPM dependency conflicts

Tags: npm, astrojs

I've tried a lot of different things to fix up my astro package. I'm installing it into my laptop for the first time. It works on my other laptop, but I'm having real trouble with it at the moment. I'm not sure how to tackle this and would appreciate further suggestions. Thanks for your help.

- Node version: 18.16.1
- NPM version: 9.5.1

Here are all the things I've tried.

`npm i`

```
npm ERR! While resolving: @onwidget/astrowind@0.9.8
npm ERR! Found: astro@2.10.4
npm ERR! node_modules/astro
npm ERR!   dev astro@"^2.4.5" from the root project

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer astro@"^1.2.1" from @astrolib/seo@0.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@astrolib/seo
npm ERR!   dev @astrolib/seo@"^0.3.0" from the root project

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
```

`npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for astro-compress@^1.1.42.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

`npm i --force`

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @astrolib/seo@0.3.1
npm WARN Found: astro@2.10.4
npm WARN node_modules/astro
npm WARN   dev astro@"^2.4.5" from the root project
npm WARN   5 more (@astrojs/image, @astrojs/tailwind, @astrojs/vercel, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer astro@"^1.2.1" from @astrolib/seo@0.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/@astrolib/seo
npm WARN   dev @astrolib/seo@"^0.3.0" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: astro@1.9.2
npm WARN node_modules/astro
npm WARN   peer astro@"^1.2.1" from @astrolib/seo@0.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@astrolib/seo
npm WARN     dev @astrolib/seo@"^0.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for astro-compress@^1.1.42.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

`npm audit fix`

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/username/.npm/_logs/debug.log
```

`npm i --package-lock-only`

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @onwidget/astrowind@0.9.8
npm ERR! Found: astro@2.10.4
npm ERR! node_modules/astro
npm ERR!   dev astro@"^2.4.5" from the root project

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer astro@"^1.2.1" from @astrolib/seo@0.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@astrolib/seo
npm ERR!   dev @astrolib/seo@"^0.3.0" from the root project
```

`npm i --package-lock-only --legacy-peer-deps`

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for astro-compress@^1.1.42.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing compress references in the astro config file and removing compress from the package.json file, I fixed it.

Seems there's an ongoing issue to resolve this.

https://github.com/astro-community/astro-compress/issues/163